# Finding all combinations by groups PySpark

Tags: pyspark, combinations

I would like to find all the possible combination within an Iterable object.

My input is

```
Object1|DrDre|1.0
Object1|Plane and a Disaster|2.0
Object1|Tikk Takk Tikk|3.5
Object1|Tennis Dope|5.0
Object2|DrDre|11.0
Object2|Plane and a Disaster|14.0
Object2|Just My Luck|2.0
Object2|Tennis Dope|45.0
```

The expected output would be something like this:

```
[(('DrDre', 'Plane and a Disaster'), (11.0, 14.0, 1.0, 2.0)),
(('DrDre', 'Tikk Takk Tikk'), (1.0, 3.5)),
(('DrDre', 'Tennis Dope'), (11.0, 45.0, 1.0, 5.0)),
(('Plane and a Disaster', 'Tikk Takk Tikk'), (2.0, 3.5)),
(('Plane and a Disaster', 'Tennis Dope'), (14.0, 45.0, 2.0, 5.0)),
(('Tikk Takk Tikk', 'Tennis Dope'), (3.5, 45.0)),
(('DrDre', 'Just My Luck'), (11.0, 2.0)),
(('Plane and a Disaster', 'Just My Luck'), (14.0, 2.0)),
(('Just My Luck', 'Tennis Dope'), (2.0, 45.0))]
```

This is my current code, which does not give me the right combinations in the end.

```
def iterate(iterable):
    r = []
    for v1_iterable in iterable:
        for v2 in v1_iterable:
            r.append(v2)

    return tuple(r)

def parseVector(line):
    '''
    Parse each line of the specified data file, assuming a "|" delimiter.
    Converts each rating to a float
    '''
    line = line.split("|")
    return line[0],(line[1],float(line[2]))

def FindPairs(object_id,items_with_usage):
    '''
    For each objects, find all item-item pairs combos. (i.e. items with the same user) 
    '''
    for item1,item2 in combinations(items_with_usage,2):
        return (item1[0],item2[0]),(item1[1],item2[1])


''' 
Obtain the sparse object-item matrix:
    user_id -> [(object_id_1, rating_1),
               [(object_id_2, rating_2),
                ...]
'''
object_item_pairs = lines.map(parseVector).groupByKey().map(
    lambda p: sampleInteractions(p[0],p[1],500)).cache()


'''
Get all item-item pair combos:
    (item1,item2) ->    [(item1_rating,item2_rating),
                         (item1_rating,item2_rating),
                         ...]
'''

pairwise_objects = object_item_pairs.filter(
    lambda p: len(p[1]) > 1).map(
    lambda p: findItemPairs(p[0],p[1])).groupByKey()



x = pairwise_objects.mapValues(iterate)
x.collect()
```

This only gives me back the first pair, and nothing else.

[(('DrDre', 'Plane and a Disaster'), (11.0, 14.0, 1.0, 2.0))]

Did I misunderstand the functionality of the combinations() function?

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: you put the `return` command inside the _for_ loop, that means that the loop will end at the first cycle. That's why you have only the first pair, because you are not storing all of the elements of `combinations(items_with_usage,2)` , you are returning only the first pair of items

Comment: Ah, great thank you titiro89!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can transform your FindPairs in this way

```
def FindPairs(object_id,items_with_usage):
'''
For each objects, find all item-item pairs combos. (i.e. items with the same user) 
'''
t = []   
for item1,item2 in combinations(items_with_usage,2):
    t.append(((item1[0],item2[0]),(item1[1],item2[1])))
return t
```

Now, your function will return a list with all the pairs of the combination.

Then

```
pairwise_objects= pairwise_objects.filter(lambda p: len(p[1]) > 1)
pairwise_objects= pairwise_objects.map(lambda p: FindPairs(p[0],p[1]))

[[(('DrDre', 'Plane and a Disaster'), (1.0, 2.0)),
(('DrDre', 'Tikk Takk Tikk'), (1.0, 3.5)),
(('DrDre', 'Tennis Dope'), (1.0, 5.0)),
(('Plane and a Disaster', 'Tikk Takk Tikk'), (2.0, 3.5)),
(('Plane and a Disaster', 'Tennis Dope'), (2.0, 5.0)),
(('Tikk Takk Tikk', 'Tennis Dope'), (3.5, 5.0))], # end of the first line of the RDD
[(('DrDre', 'Plane and a Disaster'),(11.0, 14.0)),
(('DrDre', 'Just My Luck'), (11.0, 2.0)),
(('DrDre', 'Tennis Dope'), (11.0, 45.0)), 
(('Plane and a Disaster', 'Just My Luck'), (14.0, 2.0)),
(('Plane and a Disaster', 'Tennis Dope'), (14.0, 45.0)),
(('Just My Luck', 'Tennis Dope'), (2.0, 45.0))]]
```

Use flatMap (so you will have a single line with all of your pairs) before grouping your RDD and applying your function

```
pairwise_objects=pairwise_objects.flatMap(lambda p: p).groupByKey().mapValues(iterate)
```

Final output:

```
[(('DrDre', 'Tennis Dope'), (1.0, 5.0, 11.0, 45.0)),
(('DrDre', 'Plane and a Disaster'), (1.0, 2.0, 11.0, 14.0)), 
(('Plane and a Disaster', 'Tennis Dope'), (2.0, 5.0, 14.0, 45.0)), 
(('Plane and a Disaster', 'Just My Luck'), (14.0, 2.0)),
(('Plane and a Disaster', 'Tikk Takk Tikk'), (2.0, 3.5)),
(('DrDre', 'Tikk Takk Tikk'), (1.0, 3.5)),
(('Tikk Takk Tikk', 'Tennis Dope'), (3.5, 5.0)), 
(('DrDre', 'Just My Luck'), (11.0, 2.0)), 
(('Just My Luck', 'Tennis Dope'), (2.0, 45.0))]
```